# What is the logo I'm expecting if Play Games is used as a Sign-In method?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-play-games

I'm flutter to try to use the Sign-in method for Play Games. Should I be expecting the logo for the Play Games? Or it should still be Google logo? I'm actually getting confused if I need to sign in first to Google before signing to Game Services. Currently it is having the Google logo.

This is the code I'm using and here is the package link: https://pub.dev/packages/games_services

```
    final gameAccount = await GamesServices.signIn();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you sign in to Google it will be showing the Google logo and if you are signing in to play games I will show the respected play games logo.

Comment: Then it means I am doing it wrong since the logo is still google?